# Difference between these 2 LINQ queries using Azure mobile client

Tags: c#, linq, azure-mobile-services

So I'm having issues with this LINQ query I had been using for some time, and now it seems to not be working as expected.

```
messagesWithoutConditional =
                    await
                    MobileServiceInstance.GetSyncTable<Messages>()
                        .OrderByDescending(key => key.SentDate)
                        .Take(50)
                        .Where(
                            p =>
                            (p.Uuid == myUuid && p.RecipientUuid == otherUuid) ||
                            (p.Uuid == otherUuid && p.RecipientUuid == myUuid))
                        .ToListAsync();
```

So lets say I have this query that simply returns the last 50 messages sent between 2 parties. Now if I want to add an additional condition that the 50 messages should also be before a certain date I would expect to do something like this

```
messagesWithConditional =
                    await
                    MobileServiceInstance.GetSyncTable<Messages>()
                        .OrderByDescending(key => key.SentDate)
                        .Take(50)
                        .Where(
                            p =>
                            ((p.Uuid == myUuid && p.otherUuid == recipientUuid) ||
                            (p.Uuid == otherUuid && p.RecipientUuid == myUuid))
                              && p.SentDate < 'some date')
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Lets suppose I should expect this to return 40 messages, but it returns 0. However, if I alternate the query into this

```
messagesWithConditional = messagesWithoutConditional.Where(p => p.SentDate < 'some date').ToList();
```

then I will receive the 40 expected messages by querying the result of my original expression.

How is the second approach any different from the first? Ideally I would like to use the `&&` operator to add a new conditional expression rather than break off into a second `where` clause

**Edit**

I should also note that the times are in UTC, and the `SentDate` attribute is of type `DateTimeOffset`

As of right now it appears to be a bug, unless some other insight is made. Please refer to the [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/117) report for more information

Comment: The only difference between them is that the second one will be done in memory, and the other will be done in the database. This leads me to believe that the database and your server are running on different time zones (and your 'some date' does not have timezone information attached)

Comment: You can also confirm this by adding `.Where(p => p.SentDate < 'some date')` immediately after the first where, but before `ToListAsync` (should give the same results as the condition within the same where clause)

Comment: @Rob yes I had tried that before and indeed I got the same result, i.e., 0. However I'm not sure why the conditional approach won't work if I am still using a corresponding UTC time. For example, if I take some random middle point in my `messagesWithoutConditional` structure to use that as the `SentDate` such as `messagesWithoutConditional[9].SentDate` I still receive 0 results

Comment: What happens if you pass in `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` as 'some date'?

Comment: As expected that returns all 50 messages. Which makes me think that the `DateTimeOffset` I pick is somehow behaving strangely

Comment: Can you show us how you're creating the time? I still think it's very likely that you might be passing a time, which when converted to UTC, is smaller than the timestamps of all the messages

Comment: You can check this: `var testDate = someDate.ToUniversalTime()` and then inspect the time to see if it is actually what you expect it to be

Comment: The time is actually created on the server when a new message is sent `var message = new Messages
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Uuid = uuid,
                    RecipientUuid = recipientUuid,
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    Content = content,
                    DeviceToken = deviceToken,
                    SentDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                    RecipientPlatform = recipientPlatform.ToString()
                };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108346/discussion-between-dillon-drobena-and-rob).

Comment: I recommend that you use Fiddler or log your outgoing requests with a delegating handler. Then you can see exactly what is being sent to the server and test manually with a REST client. For an example of a logging delegating handler, see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L63

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I doubt that would be very helpful in this case because there is no network request. `SyncTable` is a local data store so the server isn't involved. At least in this instance.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part! It looks like a bug, we'll investigate.

Answer (score 2):

`.Where` should be put before the `.OrderByDescending` and `.Take(50)`

Comment: Although I agree this should be the correct approach, and in fact using the regular azure tables this approach does work. However, when using `SyncTables` the outcome isn't as expected